# Error from getWindowManager in DisplayMetrics declaration error in Android

Tags: java, android, android-windowmanager

I'm designing my first android app, and part of that requires getting the screen size. I'm using the `DisplayMetrics`object in the standard way:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); //the error is on all 3 methods here
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

But I am getting an Invalid method declaration error on the 2nd line, on each of the 3 methods. This code is in my mainactivity.java file, created as an empty activity. None of the alterations suggested in other questions help here. I have tried the (Activity) cast and getContext() methods.

This is the whole file:

```
package com.example.android.cloudmusic;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    }
}
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error ?? and on which line it shows ??

Comment: There error shows on the line `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);`, each of the 3 methods shows an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use this code inside onCreate method and not outside. Remove unnecessary braces and its all good.

```
package com.example.android.cloudmusic;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
      int height = metrics.heightPixels;
      int width = metrics.widthPixels;
      // use these height and width here onwards.. 
  }
}
```

Comment: That works! Thanks. Can you reference those variables outside the method? I couldn't declare them public.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept it as answer if it helped. And you can declare them public and use it here in oncreate.